# Can't get AppUserId of current Metro App

Tags: c#, c++, windows-8

I use `GetApplicationUserModelId()` to get app user Id of the current application. Then using `ActivateApplication()` to start Metro App.

But with some apps in login screen such as Mail, People and SkyDrive I can't get `AppUserId`.

How can I get it?